# Creating a for loop to add variables into Gurobi Optimizer without redundant ones

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I am trying to add variables in Gurobi. I have the following code:

```
from gurobipy import *
rangevalue = list(range(8,13))
E = [6, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2]

y = [(m.addVar(name="y%s" % str([i+1, rangevalue[0] - t])
               .format(i+1, rangevalue[0] - t))) for i,t in enumerate(E)]
m.update()
y  #You can directly run this code and see the following output:

[<gurobi.Var y[1, 2]>,
 <gurobi.Var y[2, 5]>,
 <gurobi.Var y[3, 4]>,
 <gurobi.Var y[4, 6]>,
 <gurobi.Var y[5, 4]>,
 <gurobi.Var y[6, 6]>,
 <gurobi.Var y[7, 3]>,
 <gurobi.Var y[8, 7]>,
 <gurobi.Var y[9, 4]>,
 <gurobi.Var y[10, 6]>]
```

which is what I want. However, I also want to add more variables when `rangevalue` is `[1]`, `[2]`,`[3]`,`[4]`.....max in `rangevalue`. My rangevalue is not limited to the range (8,13), it can be higher. So, based on this how can I construct a loop to add all `y` variables?

Here is my failed attempt:

```
for k in range(rangevalue)
    y[k] = [(m.addVar(name="y%s" % str([i+1, rangevalue[k] - t])
                   .format(i+1, rangevalue[k] - t))) for i,t in enumerate(E)]
```

Comment: If you want to add multiple variables at once, you should use the addVars method instead. This does not work for duplicate keys obviously, so you need to use a unique list E, since you do not want to add the same variable twice. You can supply multiple iterables and variables will be added for the cartesian product of the iterables. E. g. m.addVars(rangevalue, E, name="y") Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Well, not exactly. You understand my problem, but your example code is not true. addVars create variables as: `y[rangevalue[1], E[1]]` and so on. If we try to use it (you can also try), it says 'Duplicate keys in Model.addVars()' which is true because `rangevalue = [8,9,10,11,12]`.

Comment: So, it produces: `y[8,6],  y[8,3], y[8,4], y[8,2], y[8,4]...'. As it is noticed, the function tried to produce `y[8,4]` several times which caused the warning to show up. I don't know if there is a way to do what I am looking for with addVars (pretty sure, there should be a sophisticated way). But, I am pretty sure we can do what I am looking for with a for loop and addVar.  Just to summarize what I want: `y[1,2], y[1,3], y[1,4], y[1,5], y[1,6], y[2,5], y[2,6], y[2,7], y[2,8], y[2,9]....` for all `i`s where `i` is my first index. Hope you can find a formulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just found my own answer and sharing here. Maybe someone can benefit:

```
for i in range(I):
    for k in range(len(rangevalue)):
        t = E[i]
        y[i+1, rangevalue[k] - t] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY,
           name="y%s" % str([i+1, rangevalue[k] - t]))
m.update()        
y
```

Output:

```
{(1, 2): <gurobi.Var y[1, 2]>,
 (1, 3): <gurobi.Var y[1, 3]>,
 (1, 4): <gurobi.Var y[1, 4]>,
 (1, 5): <gurobi.Var y[1, 5]>,
 (1, 6): <gurobi.Var y[1, 6]>,
 (2, 5): <gurobi.Var y[2, 5]>,
 (2, 6): <gurobi.Var y[2, 6]>,
 (2, 7): <gurobi.Var y[2, 7]>,
 (2, 8): <gurobi.Var y[2, 8]>,
 (2, 9): <gurobi.Var y[2, 9]>,
 (3, 4): <gurobi.Var y[3, 4]>,
 (3, 5): <gurobi.Var y[3, 5]>,
 (3, 6): <gurobi.Var y[3, 6]>,
 (3, 7): <gurobi.Var y[3, 7]>,
 (3, 8): <gurobi.Var y[3, 8]>,
 (4, 6): <gurobi.Var y[4, 6]>,
 (4, 7): <gurobi.Var y[4, 7]>,
 (4, 8): <gurobi.Var y[4, 8]>,
 (4, 9): <gurobi.Var y[4, 9]>,
 (4, 10): <gurobi.Var y[4, 10]>,
 (5, 4): <gurobi.Var y[5, 4]>,
 (5, 5): <gurobi.Var y[5, 5]>,
 (5, 6): <gurobi.Var y[5, 6]>,
 (5, 7): <gurobi.Var y[5, 7]>,
 (5, 8): <gurobi.Var y[5, 8]>,
 (6, 6): <gurobi.Var y[6, 6]>,
 (6, 7): <gurobi.Var y[6, 7]>,
 (6, 8): <gurobi.Var y[6, 8]>,
 (6, 9): <gurobi.Var y[6, 9]>,
 (6, 10): <gurobi.Var y[6, 10]>,
 (7, 3): <gurobi.Var y[7, 3]>,
 (7, 4): <gurobi.Var y[7, 4]>,
 (7, 5): <gurobi.Var y[7, 5]>,
 (7, 6): <gurobi.Var y[7, 6]>,
 (7, 7): <gurobi.Var y[7, 7]>,
 (8, 7): <gurobi.Var y[8, 7]>,
 (8, 8): <gurobi.Var y[8, 8]>,
 (8, 9): <gurobi.Var y[8, 9]>,
 (8, 10): <gurobi.Var y[8, 10]>,
 (8, 11): <gurobi.Var y[8, 11]>,
 (9, 4): <gurobi.Var y[9, 4]>,
 (9, 5): <gurobi.Var y[9, 5]>,
 (9, 6): <gurobi.Var y[9, 6]>,
 (9, 7): <gurobi.Var y[9, 7]>,
 (9, 8): <gurobi.Var y[9, 8]>,
 (10, 6): <gurobi.Var y[10, 6]>,
 (10, 7): <gurobi.Var y[10, 7]>,
 (10, 8): <gurobi.Var y[10, 8]>,
 (10, 9): <gurobi.Var y[10, 9]>,
 (10, 10): <gurobi.Var y[10, 10]>}
```